# How to select div without other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to click on a div, but not in the area of another div inside a div inside the outer div.

I tried to select my other div without the inner div using :not() in the selector, but it didn't work.

```html
<div class=outer>
  <div class=inner1>
    <div class=inner2>
      <div class=notClickable>
        <div class=alsoNotClickable>
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$("div.outer:not(div.notClickable)").click(function(){
  ...
});
```

I expect that I can click inside div class=outer, but not inside div class=notClickable and its childs.

Comment: Can you modify the html? It would be much easier to add additional div to html to correct place and only attach click-event to that. Also with this example, there is not much surface to click on if .outer does not have margin/padding, so that also suggests that attaching the event more precisely could be the solution.

Comment: I can't modify the html and was to lazy to add example div styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is adding [`stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) on the non clickable divs.

> The stopPropagation() method of the Event interface prevents further
>   propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases.

```js
$("div.outer").click(function() {
  console.log("click");
});

$("div.notClickable").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$("div.alsoNotClickable").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.outer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}

.notClickable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.alsoNotClickable {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=outer>
  <div class=inner1>
    <div class=inner2>
      <div class=notClickable>
        <div class=alsoNotClickable>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can check the `target` property of the event. If it matches the element you hooked the event to then you know that the event has not bubbled up from a child. Try this:

```js
$("div.outer").click(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is('div.outer')) {
    console.log('You clicked the outer div');
  } else {
    console.log('You clicked a child div');
  }
});
```

```css
div.outer,
div.outer div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  Outer
  <div class="inner1">
    Child
    <div class="inner2">
      Child
      <div class="notClickable">
        Child
        <div class="alsoNotClickable">
          Child
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can stop the propagation by adding this line to your function:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Eg:

```
$("div.outer:not(div.notClickable)").click(function(event) {
  ...
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cnqpmk8j/) where i use the `click function`. Let me know if that would fits you :)

Comment: This method works like the solutioned answer, but is in fact the shorter one :D

Comment: Probably the answer was uploaded when I was writing mine xD. Well chose the one that fits you better :)

Answer (score -2):

Assign an ID to the div you want to select. Then select the ID.

Comment: This does not solve the problem the op has, the problem is event bubbling from child elements to the parent.